# Count rows in a dataset filtered by multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I have a dataset I need to filter in a very specific way and then count the number of rows in it. I've been sitting on this problem for almost three hours but for no use.

I need to perform the following filters on the dataset:

1. remove all duplicates from only one text-based column (column A), and let the other column reorganize accordingly.
2. keep only rows where column B is = 'O'
3. keep only rows where column C is not empty.

but I don't want to store this new filtered dataset anywhere, I just need to know how many rows will it contain. so the filtration and counting of rows need to happen in a single command.

any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why don't you want to store the filtered dataset? First make it work, then optimize the execution.

Comment: I don't want to store the filtered data set because it will take up space in the sheet, and I want it to look clean for the work presentation.

Comment: How about deleting the stuff again after the counting?

Comment: would have worked, except I need it to update automatically when new data is added to the row dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A1:C, 
 "select *", 0), 
 "select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3 is not null and Col2 ='O'", 0), 
 "select count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0))
```

[image]